# Fill up empty cells in the dataframe with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The important combination of columns: ServerHostingCustomersId, NewValue, OldValue and year+month. For every ServerHostingCustomersId, i need to fill the empty Dataframe.NewValue. If it is empty then all the previous cells int the column should be filled with an old value.

[image]

In the image you can see that it has been sorted by ServerHostingCustomersId  and year+month.

What i expect:

The NewValue column to be filled pseudocode:

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
if df['NewValue'] == 'NaN':
df['NewValue'][i-1] = df['OldValue']
```

df.fillna(method='ffill') 
   in words:  for every unique ServerHostingCustomersId
  if the NewValue is empty - replace it with OldValue so it should be 
  df['NewValue'][i] = df['OldValue'][i-1]

```
  In this example, take OldValue - '60' and paste it in between ['year+month'] 201401 till 201404, and if the NewValue '62' occurs then it continues till the next NewValue - between ['year+month'] 201406 till 201412.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to make some assumptions based on how your wrote your question. Assuming the DataFrame is called `df`. You can do this in one line:

```
 df = df.fillna(method='ffil')
```

The documentation is here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: could you may be look at the question once again?

Comment: What is the answer not doing?